# Вопрос про правильный выбор типа для методов и полей десериализуемого объекта

Tags: c++, типы

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Packet
{
    public:
    // ...
    private:
    Header Header_;
    Payload Payload_;
};

class Header
{
    public:
    // ...
    uint16_t GetPayloadSize();
    private:
    // ...
    uint16_t PayloadSize;
};

class Payload
{
    public:
    // ...
    uint16_t GetSize();
    private:
    uint16_t Size;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> Data;
};
```

Предположим, что тип `Packet` умеет десериализоваться из потока байтов.
Также предположим, что по спецификации полезная нагрузка пакета может иметь максимальный размер в 2^16 [0; 65 535], и в потоке байтов под поле `Header::PayloadSize` отводится строго 2 байта.

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем.

Какой, с теоретическо-академической точки зрения, тип лучше использовать для следующих вещей:

- Возвращаемый тип для метода `Header::GetPayloadSize()`;
- Возвращаемый тип для метода `Payload::GetSize()`;
- Тип поля `Payload::Size`.

С одной стороны, `size_t` более удобен для пользователя, потому что с размерами обычно работают через соответствующий специальный тип. То есть, при использовании типа `size_t` элементарно будет гораздо меньше болеть голова о всяких там неявных преобразованиях к `int` и возможных переполнениях в арифметических выражениях.

С другой стороны, `uint16_t` делает интерфейсы более явными. Когда пользователя будет запрашивать размер полезной нагрузки, он будет совершенно ясно видеть, чем ограничен верхний предел этого значения. Однако, появляется много головной, которая связана с прослеживанием того, что нигде не происходит случайного переполнения или неожиданного неявного преобразования.

Comment: uint16_t делает явными не интерфейсы, а implementation details.

Comment: Те же типы, что и соответствующие члены класса (сделать алиасы для них типа `size_type` или `value_type`). Типы этих членов задавать шаблонными параметрами, если надо.

Comment: можно перейти на язык ada, где можно явно задавить диапазоны для целых чисел и нет никаких случайных переполнений или неявных преобразований

Comment: Мне кажется голова будет болеть в любом случае. Есть еще вариант использовать `ptrdiff_t` (вместо нестандартного `ssize_t`).